# How do I locate and move files on a file system?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to look up all Excel files in a folder and move them to a different folder. This needs to be run as a .py file and not from IDLE. The part of the code im having trouble with is below.

```
Path = input("Please enter the filepath u wish to search")
dirs = os.listdir( "path" )
for filename in dirs:
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        shutil.move('dirs', "C:\\Folder Sorter\\Excel")
```

I enter this **"C:\Move"** for the input its a folder I created with xlsx files in to be moved. I'm getting the below error. Any help wuould be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Toms Stuff/Programing/Python/Git FileSorter/Git File Sorter Final Part 2.py", line 24, in <module>
    dirs = os.listdir( "path" )
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'path/*.*'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks OK, with some errors...

1) *os.listdir( "path" )* your path is stored in variable Path, but you call listdir function with string "path"

2) shutil move needs 2 arguments: source file and a folder for result

```
Path = input("Please enter the filepath u wish to search")
dirs = os.listdir( Path ) #because "path" is string and not your variable...
for filename in dirs:
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        shutil.move(Path +"/"+filename, "C:/Folder Sorter/Excel")
```